# Desactivación de un usuario en Laravel

Tags: laravel, login

Hace poco me aclararon como evitar que un usuario inactivo acceda con sus credenciales. En el método `login()` del controlador `LoginController` me sugirieron sobrescribir el método `credentials()`, así:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $credenciales = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    //añadimos el valor de activo a S, para que sea correcto
    $credenciales = array_add($credenciales, 'activo', 'S');
    return $credenciales ;
}
```

Funciona para bloquear al usuario, pero es insuficiente para lo que pretendo. Intento que si un usuario está inactivo, le redirija a una página informándole de su situación, y no le permita acceder. Además, si el usuario es inactivado por un administrador cuando ya está logueado, cualquier enlace que pulse o lo que haga a partir de ese momento deberá desloguearle y redirigirle a la página donde se le informa de que ha sido inactivado.

Por lo que he leido, creo que esto puede hacerse con un middleware, pero, francamente, no sé por donde empezar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La mejor forma de hacer esto es con un middleware, el cual te permite evaluar la solicitud PHP antes de llegar al controlador. Para este caso puedes crear un nuevo middleware o modificando app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

En caso que crees uno nuevo, deberás aplicarlo a las mismas rutas que utilizan el middleware auth.

En el middleware tendrías algo así:

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && auth()->user()->active == 0) {

    // usuario con sesión iniciada pero inactivo

    // cerramos su sesión
    Auth::guard()->logout();

    // invalidamos su sesión
    $request->session()->invalidate();

    // redireccionamos a donde queremos
    redirect('/ruta-para-usuario-desactivado');
}
```

Comment: Respuesta simple y genial, como siempre, Shaz. Así da gusto. Solo una aclaración. Lo que he expermientado ha sido siempre con Auth::check(). Que diferencia hay con Auth::guard($guard)->check()? Gracias.

Comment: Puedes continuar usando `Auth::check()`, el ejemplo que te pasé está utilizando un Guard específico y no el predeterminado (por así decirlo).

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacer la autenticación de esta otra manera.

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = array('username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password, "status" => 1);
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials, false)) {

            return redirect()->intended('/');
        } else {
            //when echoing something here it is always displayed thus admin login is just refreshed.
            return redirect('/login')->withInput()->with('message', 'Login Failed o cuenta desactivada');
        }
    }
```